# Lock Question - When is an Update (U) lock issued?

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to resolve a deadlock problem. The transaction that is getting rolled back is attempting to issue an Update (U) lock on a resource that another transaction has an Exclusive  (X) lock on. According to Books Online (`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519.aspx`), an Update lock is supposed to prevent deadlocks, not cause them.

So, my question is, why/when is an Update lock applied to a resource? We're a little confused about this because the resource that is attempting to have the Update lock applied to `will not` be updated by the process that is having the transaction rolled back.

Thanks for your help on this.

Randy

Comment: What are the transaction isolation levels of the stuff going on with the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a whole universe of "what if" behind what causes deadlocks (by which I mean, there's no way to tell from your initial post what's really going on). Could be table locks, could be locks on indexes; could be oustanding transactions you are not aware of; could be table header locks, could be tempdb issues (very unlikely), who knows?

The best method I've ever found to diagnose deadlocks works like so:

- Fire up SQL Profiler, configure it with the "Deadlock Graph" and "Lock: Deadlock" events, and be sure to include the TextData column
- While Profiler is running, cause your application to generate the deadlock
- Select the "Deadlock Graph" profiler row, and you'll get a simple yet confusing graphic display of what's going on. This might help you figure out what's really going on.
- If that doesn't help, the graphic is generated by Profiler based on a very detailed lump of XML. Extract this string (select the Deadlock Graph row, Ctrl+C to copy, paste in your text editor of choice, and delete all the columns but the XML), and then review the XML (in your preferred XML editor).

To-date, once I've gotten and worked through that XML, I've always been able to figure out what was causing the deadlock.  It's a good way to learn how weird and convoluted some of SQL's internals can get.

Comment: It was through SQL Profiler and the deadlock graph it produces that clued me into the Update lock. I would just like to know  why and under what circumstances an Update lock is issued.

Comment: Its if an attempt is made to update one or more columns within one or more rows of a table. (Note that "UPDATE MyTable set colx = colx" will issue a lock, even though you're updating nothing). I'm not aware of anything else that would generate an update lock, but SQL does contain a lot of esoteric mojo. (There are schema locks, but I'm presuming you're not getting those.)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to do a bit more research to find out what is actually locking, what isolation level each query is in, etc.

Some helpful resources.

[SQL Server Transaction Isolation Levels and their Locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

[SQL Server Lock Types and Lock Hints](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Adm/SQL70Locks.htm)

Comment: Ok, but I'd like to know under what situations are an Update lock applied?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not handle your transaction isolation properly and are in serialized transaction mode.

You should

- Use the proper transaction isolation on the connection.
- Sometimes use hints on SQL, like the NoLock hint when you basically just read some data and don't do anything else with it anyway in a transaction.